# How do I limit the child's movement to inside the parent element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a webpage that has an eye in the center but the iris and pupil follow the cursor's position. I managed to get the div moving but can't seem to figure out how to limit it to the area where the eye will be.

Here's what I have so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #myId {
          width: 22px;
          height: 22px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          background-color: red;
          transition: 0.1s;
          position: relative;
        }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; border-radius: 50%; background: slateblue; position: absolute;">
    <div id="myId"></div>
  </div>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.onmousemove = function(e) { 
            var x = e.clientX; 
            var y = e.clientY; 
            document.getElementById('myId').style.marginLeft  = x+"px";
            document.getElementById('myId').style.marginTop  = y+"px";
    
        }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You would need to get the parent coords of the 4 corners, and when moving, figure out the direction and check the proper corner against parents corner coords. If the eye is inside then move div, else do nothing

Comment: Fireship released a video on the exact same topic some time ago. Might be helpful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGe3pS5LqEw